# How can I remove a shower faucet with no set screw?

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

I'm fixing a leaky shower head and am trying to take the faucet handle apart. The shower faucet is a single handle with separate temperature control, made by Delta.  [image]

There is no set screw, and I cannot figure out how to take it apart. I've tried prying it off, but it doesn't want to come off.  This is as far as I could get in trying to take it apart.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The ring that the handle screws onto should also have a set screw inside the handle socket so you can remove it.  Once removed, there is a retainer ring that holds the valve in.  Search for "Delta series 17 shower valve removal" or similar for detailed instructions and see if they match what you have.  I'd post as an answer, but not 100% sure this is the valve you have.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. There is no set screw. I just needed a little more force to wiggle it off.